# Excel vba replace comma with

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use this vba code in my sheet to replace any commas in column D with a full stop:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("D").Replace _
What:=",", Replacement:=".", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

I had it working I'm sure for a minute but then it didn't! Any ideas???

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: How is this code called?

Comment: No error, it works for everything except from "," the comma! And in the worksheet_SelectionChange

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean when you say "it doesn't work". How do you know it is not working? If it is in a `Worksheet` module, as others note, it will *only* work on that worksheet.

Comment: Wait, is the problem that it crashes or that it doesn't replace the ","?

Comment: This works on my compy, with Excel 2010.

Comment: neeko may have to give out some more information of the usable, clear, helpful kind.

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that you put the code in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.  Put the code in a module instead, then run it when you want to use it.  Then it will work for any sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You already replaced all the comma's, it's not going to work again.

Comment: Did you put a break point in the code and see if it's actually processing anything?

Comment: In the VBA window, click in the left margin.  it will put a red dot there.  That puts a break point on that line of code.  You can then step through it by hitting the F8 key.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Columns("D").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

It does work like this. Do not add the "_"

Comment: So, you mean the code is correct as presented, and it should work?

Comment: All you've done is re-posted the exact code that's already in the question (verbatim, AFAICT). What part is supposed to provide an answer?

Comment: If true, this should be a comment and not an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Where did u put the code may I ask? I put it in worksheet_selectionChange

Comment: I had posted the code in one single line. The "_" was making the macro crash.

Comment: The `_` is for line continuation.  It's not the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my damaging edit, Julien.  The new explanation is necessary for understanding, I think, so thanks for adding it.